# Analytics plugins that allow for inclusion of _trackPageLoadTime()?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, google-analytics

Are there any plugins that allow one to make use of the _trackPageLoadTime(); functionality available in the new version of Google Analytics yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google Analytics by Yoast](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-analytics-for-wordpress/) has *Custom Code* setting to add stuff to tracking code. But says that it is added before `trackPageview`, while [site speed instructions](http://www.google.com/support/analyticshelp/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1205784&topic=1120718) show it added after. Might or might not matter, I don't know.

**Update**

Plugin has been updated to [support (and default to) site speed tracking](http://yoast.com/site-speed-tracking-in-google-analytics/).

Comment: I think it does have to be after

Answer (score 0):

Why not just include the google analytics code in the functions file by hooking wp_foot?  I usually just add it that way.  Are you trying to use something like Analyticator that shows the analytics on your dashboard?

Comment: I'd love to, but I am a 'configuror' not a developer, although thinking about it, what you say makes lot's of sense and may be within my modest capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

I just released a Google Analytics plugin that includes the new track page load time.  It has an option page to enter your Google Analytics id and outputs the ga.async javascript in your footer.

You can download it on GitHub:  [C3M Google Analytics](https://github.com/c3mdigital/C3M-Google-Analytics)

Answer (score 0):

Google Analyticator has always had the option to add code before, or after initialization. We use it on all our sites and it's working great.